# Retryable annotation - Junit5 - Mockito - is it possible

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-retry

Is it possible to write unit test using Junit 5 mockito for retryable annotations?

I am having a service interface which has only one method, which downloads the file from remote url

```
@service
interface downloadpdf{
@Retryable(value = { FileNotFoundException.class, HttpClientErrorException.class }, maxAttempts = 5, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000))
public string downloadpdffile(string remoteurl, string pdfname);    
}
```

I have tried referring sites and found using Spring4JunitRunner implementation to test retry. Got confused with implementation. Is it possible to write unit test using Junit 5 mockito for retryable annotations?. Could you please elaborate on the solution here?

Comment: @cliff2310 sure..Will do

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `@SpringJUnitConfig` (which is the equivalent of the JUnit4 runner). Or `@SpringBootTest` as you are using Boot.

`@Retryable` only works with beans managed by Spring - it wraps the bean in a proxy.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRetry
public class So71849077Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So71849077Application.class, args);
    }

}

@Component
class RetryableClass {

    private SomeService service;

    void setService(SomeService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Retryable
    void retryableMethod(String in) {
        service.callme();
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    @Recover
    void recover(Exception ex, String  in) {
        service.failed();
    }

}

interface SomeService {

    void callme();

    void failed();

}
```

```java
@SpringBootTest
class So71849077ApplicationTests {

    @MockBean
    SomeService service;

    @Test
    void testRetry(@Autowired RetryableClass retryable) {
        SomeService service = mock(SomeService.class);
        retryable.setService(service);

        retryable.retryableMethod("foo");
        verify(service, times(3)).callme();
        verify(service).failed();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to implement this using Junit5.

Tried various options but that didn't help. Then after googling for few hours, got the following link and it helped to succeed.

https://doctorjw.wordpress.com/2022/04/29/spring-testing-a-single-bean-in-junit-5-springextension/

Reference code below, for detailed explanation, please refer the blog.

```
@Component
public class MyClass {
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Value("${testValue:5}")
private int value;


@Retryable(....)
public void doStuff() throws SomeException {
...
}
}
```

What I’ve discovered is, if I declare my test class this way:

```
@ExtendWith( SpringExtension.class )
@Import( { MyClass.class, ObjectMapper.class } )
@EnableRetry
public class MyClassTest {

@Autowired
private MyClass myClass;

@MockBean
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    // If we are going to jack with the object configuration,
    // we need to do so on the actual object, not the Spring proxy.
    // So, use AopTestUtils to get around the proxy to the actual obj.

    TestingUtils.setFieldValue( AopTestUtils.getTargetObject( myClass ), "value", 10 );
}

}
```

You will notice the inclusion of 1 other class, TestingUtils.class. This class looks like:

```
public class TestingUtils {

public static void setFieldValue( Object object, String fieldName, Object value ) {
    Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField( object.getClass(), fieldName );
    ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible( field );

    ReflectionUtils.setField( field, object, value );
}
}
```

All credits goes to the author of the blog.